# Avoid vendor specific prefixes in CSS

Tags: css

Looking for any method to avoid **Vendor specific prefixes** while writing css, it unnecessarily lengthens the css file.
Like while using transforms I have to write following code

```
transform:rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
-o-transform:rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
```

All 5 lines does the same thing but for different browsers. So any way to avoid it?

Comment: You're not writing it correctly; the unprefixed style should come last

Comment: but all I want is to write only once. 
cherouvim's answer suits to my need, but still a pure css solution would be great

Comment: A pure CSS solution will probably be possible in a couple of years when older versions of browsers won't be used any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A javascript based solution is http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/

> -prefix-free lets you use only unprefixed CSS properties everywhere. It works behind the scenes, adding the current browser’s prefix to any
>   CSS code, only when it’s needed.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer considered the most advanced solution to automate prefixing. You can use it in Sublime Text or Grunt or ton of other ways. It is always up to date and very convenient to use.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Sass:**

I use http://compass-style.org using Sass. Alternative to Compass would also be http://bourbon.io (a bit more lightweight, no personal experience)

Without Sass check out the other answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is also quite a good way to solve this issue.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/